# Dart on Heroku failing, missing file?

Tags: git, heroku, dart

I deployed my app to heroku using using this buildpack: https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart

It works fine locally and there were no errors in deployment, but when I start app, I get error in load configuration step (dart_config package). Heroku logs shows:

```
2014-07-01T13:29:14.754422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./dart-sdk/bin/dart bin/kompost_cmd.dart`
2014-07-01T13:29:17.097360+00:00 app[web.1]: config.yaml does not exist
```

and when I try to list deployed directory, config.yaml is present:

```
~ $ cd bin
~/bin $ ls -alF
total 16
drwx------ 2 u49334 49334 4096 Jul  1 12:56 ./
drwx------ 8 u49334 49334 4096 Jul  1 13:26 ../
-rwx------ 1 u49334 49334  412 Jul  1 12:56 config.yaml*
-rwx------ 1 u49334 49334 3135 Jul  1 12:56 kompost_cmd.dart*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u49334 49334   11 Jul  1 13:26 packages -> ../packages/
```

What could be wrong?

//edit

It is probably path error. But I load this config file from same location as dart file is, which works fine on my local machine. What is a difference?

Comment: And config.yaml is present when I list git ls-tree -r master --name-only

Comment: It looks like your `config.yaml` file is in a subdirectory called `bin`? I know very little about Dart, but when I got started on Heroku with Python I had a similar problem because my `requirements.txt` file wasn't in the root of my repository. I ended up having to move some files around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be carefull because the root path used to resolve file path is where you are when you launch your dart application.

So here, your `config.yaml` is missing because it is in `bin/` and not in `./`

Maybe the option `-p<path> or -package-root=<path>` of the dart vm can help you, [dartVM option](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart-vm.html)

Comment: Thank you, this is probably cause of my problem. Is there way to change this "working directory" to "bin"?